# Using an Interface returns undefined when retrieving values from Forms using Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm doing an Edit Profile Page using Angular 4 and I'm having trouble with the following situation:

I have this `user-profile.ts` interface

```
export interface UserProfile {

    name:string;
    email:string;

}
```

Now this is my `user-profile.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Inject} from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import { ElementRef, Directive, Renderer2, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Form } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormControlName } from '@angular/forms';

import { UserProfile } from './user-profile';

@Component({
  selector: 'user-profile',
  templateUrl: './user-profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-profile.component.css']
})

export class UserProfileComponent implements OnInit {

profileForm:FormGroup;

up: UserProfile;

  constructor(@Inject(FormBuilder) fb: FormBuilder) {

    this.profileForm = new FormGroup({
      name : new FormControl(),
      email : new FormControl()
    });


    saveUserProfile(){

    this.up.nomeCliente = this.profileForm.value.nomeCliente;

    this.up.emailCliente = this.profileForm.value.emailCliente;


      console.log(

        'Name + Email', this.up.name + ' - ' + this.up.email


      );


  }

}
```

Then, finally, my `user-profile.component.html`

```
<div class='container'>
  <form class="example-form" [formGroup]='profileForm' #pForm >

    <div class='row'>
        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
            <input type='text' name='name' formControlName='name'  matInput placeholder="Nome" value="Me">
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>

    <div class='row'>
      <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
        <input type='email' matInput name='email' formControlName='email' placeholder="Email" value="me@me.com">
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>

    <button type='submit' mat-button class='btn-primary' (click)='saveUserProfile(profileForm.value)'>Salvar</button>

  </form>
</div>
```

This is the error i'm getting:

```
UserProfileComponent.html:95 ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined
```

Can someone explain me why I'm getting this error? Shouldn't I be able to use my interface in this situation? Why?
Am I missing an import or something?
Just to remember, this is an Edit Profile area, so the user might encounter his data there and, if he changes and click save, the data will update.

Also, I've done it without using an interface and it works. I would like to understand why I can't use an interface in this situation, as it would make my code much more cleaner.

Thanks!

Comment: You never initialize your `up` property, so `up` is undefined. The interface only defines the "shape" of the property, it does not initialize it. You could define it like `up: UserProfile = {name: null, email: null};` or when you are setting the properties `this.up = {name: this.profileForm.value.name, email: this.profileForm.value.email};`

Comment: That's it. So simple! Thank you very much!